# Valgrind and Memory Leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm doing a little bit of memory profiling to my software and after running standard memory leak check with valgrind's following command

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./path_to_program
```

I got following summary:

> ==12550== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==12550==    definitely lost: 597,170 bytes in 7 blocks
>
> ==12550==    indirectly lost: 120 bytes in 10 blocks
>
> ==12550==      possibly lost: 770,281 bytes in 1,455 blocks
>
> ==12550==    still reachable: 181,189 bytes in 2,319 blocks
>
> ==12550==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==12550== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>
> ==12550== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
>
> ==12550==
>
> ==12550== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==12550== ERROR SUMMARY: 325 errors from 325 contexts (suppressed: 176 from 11)

It doesn't look quite good to me, so my question is

> Why isn't my program exploding if it has all these leaks?

And also what is the difference between:

- definitely lost
- indirectly lost
- possibly lost
- still reachable

and how can I try to fix them?

Comment: Why would you expect it to explode?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth cause it has a lot of allocated memory not freed

Comment: @Matteo: that's barely a couple MB at worst, no reason for it to "blow up" unless you're on a very constrained environment.

Comment: @Matteo Why would not freeing allocated memory cause an error? Aside from out-of-memory conditions, which are obviously not the case (only a few megabyte lost in the worst case, you probably have >1 GB).

Comment: @Mat but shouldn't memory leaks be completely avoided when programming?

Comment: Real leaks, yes, as much as possible. But your expecting your program to blow up if it leaks is not reasonable. (That's also what can make leak tracking difficult - small leaks are usually harder to pinpoint that large ones.)

Comment: @Mat I'm not on a very constrained environment but I'm afraid that changing input may cause bigger leaks. Is there a way to find out leak impact without trying all possible benchmarks?

Comment: You should definitely fix all memory leaks as you become aware of them. As well as out-of-memory and performance problems, leaks can highlight other bugs you weren't aware of. However, more allocation-related crashes (explosions) occur - not when you loose track of an allocation, but conversely - when you keep hold of memory which has been deallocated. Reading to and writing from this memory causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest visiting the [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost):

> **With Memcheck's memory leak detector, what's the difference between
>   "definitely lost", "indirectly lost", "possibly lost", "still
>   reachable", and "suppressed"?**
>
> The details are in the Memcheck section
>   of the user manual.
>
> In short:
>
> - "definitely lost" means your program is leaking memory -- fix those
>     leaks!
> - "indirectly lost" means your program is leaking memory in a
>     pointer-based structure. (E.g. if the root node of a binary tree is
>     "definitely lost", all the children will be "indirectly lost".) If you
>     fix the "definitely lost" leaks, the "indirectly lost" leaks should go
>     away.
> - "possibly lost" means your program is leaking memory, unless you're
>     doing unusual things with pointers that could cause them to point into
>     the middle of an allocated block; see the user manual for some
>     possible causes. Use `--show-possibly-lost=no` if you don't want to see
>     these reports.
> - "still reachable" means your program is probably ok -- it didn't free
>     some memory it could have. This is quite common and often reasonable.
>     Don't use `--show-reachable=yes` if you don't want to see these reports.
> - "suppressed" means that a leak error has been suppressed. There are
>     some suppressions in the default suppression files. You can ignore
>     suppressed errors.