# Simple examples to the different leak types reported by Valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

While debugging a leaky application, I noticed [many, many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valgrind) questions regarding valgrind and the different types of leaks. These questions usually have very specific examples that don't help understanding how the different types of leaks come to be. A reference is this [read the manual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956375/6271889).

What are the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for valgrind?

Answer (score 2):

I set out to write a set of very simple functions that show the different types of leaks reported by valgrind and what they mean.

My main source was this [Red Hat blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/04/23/valgrind-memcheck-different-ways-to-lose-your-memory) by Mark Wielaard, I just decided to use simpler examples.

`test.c` is:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void leaky_definitely(void)
{
    char *p;

    /* 
    This is definitely lost because the pointer is a local variable and once we
    exit the function we lose the refence to the allocated block, so there's no
    way to free this block.
    */
    p = malloc(sizeof(char));
}

char *g_p;

void leaky_still_reachable(void)
{
    /*
    This is still reachable because the pointer is a global variable that's
    preserved until the end of our program, so we could have called free on it.
    */
    g_p = malloc(sizeof(char));
}

char *leaky_array;

void leaky_possibly(void)
{
    leaky_array = malloc(3*sizeof(char));

    /*
    This is possibly lost because the allocated base pointer was lost as we
    incremented it twice, but because leaky_array still points somwewhere in the
    allocated block, we could have done something to recover the base pointer
    and then free it.

    To transform this possibly lost leak into a definitely lost leak, just
    change '2' to '3' in the loop.
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        *leaky_array = i;
        leaky_array++;
    }
}

char **double_pointer;

void leaky_indirectly(void)
{
    double_pointer = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    *double_pointer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    /*
    This will cause a definitely lost leak because double_pointer is lost. It
    will also cause an indirectly lost leak because double_pointer contined a
    pointer to another memory block.

    Indirectly lost leaks are definitely lost leaks indirectly caused by another
    definitely lost leak.
     */

    /*
    By changing the line bellow to `free(double_pointer)` we would create a
    definitely lost leak on `*double_pointer` instead of a indirectly lost.
     */
    // free(double_pointer);
    double_pointer = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    leaky_definitely();
    leaky_still_reachable();
    leaky_possibly();
    leaky_indirectly();

    return 0;
}
```

The code was built with:

```sh
gcc -Wall -O0 -g -o test test.c
```

Valgrind was run as

```
$ valgrind --show-reachable=yes --leak-check=full ./test
==26907== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26907== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26907== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26907== Command: ./test
==26907== 
==26907== 
==26907== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26907==     in use at exit: 14 bytes in 5 blocks
==26907==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 0 frees, 14 bytes allocated
==26907== 
==26907== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 5
==26907==    at 0x4C336AD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==26907==    by 0x400518: leaky_still_reachable (test.c:24)
==26907==    by 0x4005BF: main (test.c:74)
==26907== 
==26907== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 5
==26907==    at 0x4C336AD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==26907==    by 0x40059B: leaky_indirectly (test.c:53)
==26907==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:76)
==26907== 
==26907== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5
==26907==    at 0x4C336AD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==26907==    by 0x400503: leaky_definitely (test.c:13)
==26907==    by 0x4005BA: main (test.c:73)
==26907== 
==26907== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 5
==26907==    at 0x4C336AD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==26907==    by 0x400534: leaky_possibly (test.c:31)
==26907==    by 0x4005C4: main (test.c:75)
==26907== 
==26907== 9 (8 direct, 1 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==26907==    at 0x4C336AD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==26907==    by 0x400583: leaky_indirectly (test.c:52)
==26907==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:76)
==26907== 
==26907== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26907==    definitely lost: 9 bytes in 2 blocks
==26907==    indirectly lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26907==      possibly lost: 3 bytes in 1 blocks
==26907==    still reachable: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26907==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26907== 
==26907== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==26907== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```